# How to trace DMA transactions by using dma_debug?

Tags: kernel, tracing, debugfs

I am currently working on some PCI-e device stuff, that requires me to get the trace for DMA transactions on a specific (say GPU or NIC ) PCI card. After doing some research I found a useful [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604585/how-to-trace-dma) by xealits,  but it seems doesn't tell how many bytes are read/written in a certain DMA transaction. I then found a kernel module named `dma_debug` may fully meet my expectations

I tried to recompile kernel v6.7 with configure options:

```
CONFIG_DMA_API_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y
CONFIG_DMA_API_DEBUG_SG=y
CONFIG_DMA_API_DEBUG_FENCE=y
CONFIG_DMA_API_DEBUG_EVENTS=y
```

and add `dma_debug.debug_dma=1` to `grub` default booting variables. But unfortunately,
`dmesg` seems completely identical to when booting the old kernel. Also, `dma_debug` didn't show up in `/sys/kernel/debug`.

Am I missing something? How can I get the `dma_debug` to work？ If this module is deprecated, is there any substitute method?